# jQuery change class to list a links onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my menu I have jQuery changing the colour of the button once it is clicked - so this highlights the active menu.  But I want to also show where the user has already clicked, whilst the active menu stays blue.

- User clicks Menu 1 it turns blue
- User clicks Menu 2 it turns blue and Menu 1 is green
- User clicks Menu 3 it turns blue and Menu 1 and 2 are
  green etc

How do I do this?

I can show the active menu in blue, but can't work out the code to show visited (a.degrees-visited) properly.

DEMO FIDDLE:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m91kqtr3/)

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#" class="nav-left degrees hide-show default-show" rel="menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-left degrees hide-show" rel="menu2">Menu 2</a></li>   
<li><a href="#" class="nav-left degrees hide-show" rel="menu3">Menu 3</a></li>  
<li><a href="#" class="nav-left degrees hide-show" rel="menu4">Menu 4</a></li>
```

```
$('#nav li a.degrees').on('click', function(){
 $('li a.degrees-current').removeClass('degrees-current');
 $(this).addClass('degrees-current');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use toggleClass()

```
$('#nav li a.degrees').on('click', function(){
     $('li a.degrees-current').removeClass('degrees-current').addClass('degrees-visited');
     $(this).addClass('degrees-current');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0ogLwfat/)

Comment: this wouldn't work if you keep clicking through the same elements again and again!

Comment: @noob yes changing the css order could fix it http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0ogLwfat/1/

Comment: it wasn't just about CSS order it was the jQuery toogleClass which you've used earlier. Anyways you've used the right logic now!

Answer (score 0):

Just add other class:

```
$('#nav li a.degrees').on('click', function(){
 $('li a.degrees-current').removeClass('degrees-current');
 $(this).addClass('clicked');
 $(this).addClass('degrees-current');
});
```

And style that class in your CSS:

```
.clicked{
background:green;
}
```